# How to make a class method in place?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods

Is there a way to make a method in a python class modify its data in place, specifically for lists?

For example, I want to write a function that behave like `list.append()` by modifying the origonal list instead of returning a new one

I have already

```
class newlist(list):
     def add(self, otherlist):
          self = self+otherlist
```

A method written like that does not seem to modify the variable it is called on.
Obviosly, I could add `return self` at the end, but then it would have to be called with `mylist = mylist.add(stuff)` to actually modify `mylist`. How do write the function so it will modify `mylist` when called with just `mylist.add(stuff)`?

Comment: If you override `__add__` , then you can use the `+` and `+=` operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain assignment to `self` will rebind it; `self` is bound to the new object, and you've lost the reference to the original type.

The easiest approach here it to use `list`s existing overload for augmented assignment, `+=`:

```
class newlist(list):
    def add(self, otherlist):
        self += otherlist
```

That mutates `self` in place, rather than making a new object and reassigning it (it works because `list` is a mutable type; it wouldn't work for an immutable type without an overload for `+=`). You could also implement it as `self.extend(otherlist)`, or for extra cleverness, don't even bother to write a Python level implementation at all and just alias the existing `list` method:

```
class newlist(list):
    add = list.__iadd__ # Or add = list.extend
```

Since the definition of `add` is basically identical to existing `+=` or `list.extend` behavior, just under a new name, aliasing concisely gets the performance of the built-in function; the only downside is that introspection (`print(newline.add)`) will not indicate that the function's name is `add` (because it's `__iadd__` or `extend`; aliasing doesn't change the function metadata).

Answer (score 2):

Since `newlist` is a subclass of `list` it already has a method that does exactly what you want: `extend`.  You don't have to write any code in `newlist` at all.

But if you really want to reinvent the wheel you can call extend within your new add method and get the same result:

```
class newlist(list):
     def add(self, otherlist):
          self.extend(otherlist)

mylist = newlist()
mylist.append(0)
mylist.extend([1,2,3])
print(mylist)

mylist = newlist()
mylist.append(0)
mylist.add([1,2,3])
print(mylist)
```

> > > [0, 1, 2, 3]
> > >       [0, 1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the in-place addition `+=` for your function:

```
class newlist(list):
    def add(self, other):
        self += other

a = newlist([1,2])
b = newlist([3,4])
a.add(b)

a
# returns:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```